# PowerShell: Iterating Multiple Variables not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I am trying to iterate over an array `$dailyTasks` to find 'Blank' i.e. `''` values in the `EmployeeName` column and inject names from another array into those empty values.

Example of what the array looks like before the `for loop` starts:

```markdown
| Task  | EmployeeName | EmployeeName2 |
|-------|--------------|---------------|
| Task1 |              |               |
| Task2 | Person Y     |               |
| Task3 |              |               |
| Task4 | Person Z     | Person X      |
```

This is my for loop code that produces an undesired result. `$randomisedUsers` is an Object[]

```
$randomisedUsers | Group-Object { $_ -in ($randomisedUsers | Select-Object -Last 2) } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -eq 'True') {
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $dailyTasks.Count; $i++) {
                if ($dailyTasks[$i].Task -eq 'Task4') {
                    $dailyTasks[$i].EmployeeName = $_.Group.EmployeeName[0]
                    $dailyTasks[$i].EmployeeName2 = $_.Group.EmployeeName[1]
                }
            }
    } else {
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $dailyTasks.Count; $i++) {
                if ($dailyTasks[$i].EmployeeName -eq '') {
                    if ($_.Count -gt '1') {
                        for ($x = 0; $x -lt $_.Group.EmployeeName.Count; $x++) {
                            $dailyTasks[$i].EmployeeName = $_.Group.EmployeeName[$x]
                        }
                    } else {
                        $dailyTasks[$i].EmployeeName = $_.Group.EmployeeName
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Result:

```markdown
| Task  | EmployeeName | EmployeeName2 |
|-------|--------------|---------------|
| Task1 | Person A     |               |
| Task2 | Person Y     |               |
| Task3 | Person A     |               |
| Task4 | Person Z     | Person X      |
```

The problem here is that `$_.Group.EmployeeName` contains two objects but for whatever reason the result table doesnt populate Person B in the array:

```
$_.Group.EmployeeName

{Person A, Person B}
```

The desired result in this case is:

```
| Task  | EmployeeName | EmployeeName2 |
|-------|--------------|---------------|
| Task1 | Person A     |               |
| Task2 | Person Y     |               |
| Task3 | Person B     |               |
| Task4 | Person Z     | Person X      |
```

Im not completely sure where im going wrong in my for loops and i've been stuck on this for a while...

TIA

Comment: What is `$_`?  This automatic variable is usually used in a `ForEach-Object -Process` block however there is not one in your code.

Comment: @Daniel correct its from a ForEach block. Apologies i didnt think it was necessary to include it

Comment: As an aside: You probably meant `$_.Count -gt 1` - no reason to use `'1'`, which suggests _lexical_ comparison; however, it is the  data type of the _LHS_ that matters: the RHS is coerced to the LHS' data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally use something like this:

```
$csv = @'
Task,EmployeeName,EmployeeName2 
Task1,,
Task2,Person Y,
Task3,,
Task4,Person Z,Person X      
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$fillEmployees = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(
    'Person A'
    'Person B'
)

foreach($line in $csv)
{
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line.EmployeeName))
    {
        $line.EmployeeName = $fillEmployees[0]
        $fillEmployees.RemoveAt(0)
    }
}
```

The flow is quite simple, if the loop finds a value in **EmployeeName** that is null or has white spaces it will replace that value with the index 0 of `$fillEmployees` and then remove that index 0 from the list.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish with your code, but if you have an array of the type `System.Array` filled with *random names* which will be used to *fill* this empty values on **EmployeeName** you can convert that `Array` to an `ArrayList` which will allow you to use the `.RemoveAt(..)` method:

```
PS /> $fillEmployees = 0..10 | ForEach-Object {"Employee {0}" -f [char](Get-Random -Minimum 65 -Maximum 90)}

PS /> $fillEmployees
Employee J
Employee S
Employee D
Employee P
Employee O
Employee E
Employee M
Employee K
Employee R
Employee F
Employee A

PS /> $fillEmployees.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Attempting to Remove an item from an `Array` would result in the following:

```
PS /> $fillEmployees.RemoveAt(0)
Exception calling "RemoveAt" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At line:1 char:1
...
...
```

However if convert it to an `ArrayList` (not convert it but copy it):

```
PS /> $fillEmployees = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$fillEmployees

PS /> $fillEmployees.RemoveAt(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer, i will try and implement it on my side now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @ayushlal Show me where the "employees to fill" are coming from and I'll show you how you can implement this solution.

Comment: @ayushlal see my edit, hopefully makes sense.